# Normal mapping in OpenGL immediate mode

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-compat

I have been trying to load various texture types onto my model, so far I have just loaded a diffuse texture onto it, which works fine. However, I have been getting stuck on using a normal map, the map is read in from file correctly however I cannot get it to act like a normal map as opposed to a diffuse map. (Image for clarification).

[image: Normal map being used as a diffuse map]

Below is the load texture code: (BMP is a Bitmap file reader struct)

```
BMP tempTexturedData(path);

mWidth = tempTexturedData.bmp_info_header.width;
mHeight = tempTexturedData.bmp_info_header.height;

tempTexturedData.ConvertToRGB();
std::cout << path << " is loaded\n";

glGenTextures(1, &mID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mID);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, mWidth, mHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tempTexturedData.rgbData.data());

return true;
```

Here is the render code:

```
glPushMatrix();

        glTranslatef(mPosition.x, mPosition.y, mPosition.z);

        glScalef(mScale.x, mScale.y, mScale.z);

        glRotatef(mRotation.x, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glRotatef(mRotation.y, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glRotatef(mRotation.z, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

        if (mTexture != nullptr) {
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTexture->GetID());
            glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
        }

        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        for (int i = 0; i < mesh.indices.size(); i++) {
            glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, &(mesh.meshMaterial.Ka.x));
            glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, &(mesh.meshMaterial.Kd.x));
            glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, &(mesh.meshMaterial.Ks.x));
            glMaterialf(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, mesh.meshMaterial.illum);

            glTexCoord2fv(&mesh.verticies[mesh.indices[i]].textureCoordinate.x);
            glNormal3fv(&mesh.verticies[mesh.indices[i]].normal.x);
            glVertex3fv(&mesh.verticies[mesh.indices[i]].position.x);
        }
        glEnd();

        glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: While there are ways to make normal maps work to some degree in fixed-function OpenGL, it would be much better for you to ditch the out-dated stuff and move on to learning shaders.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to use immediate mode for my University coursework.

Comment: Strange coursework that asks you to do something that isn't really possible. Not in a correct way, at least. Are they asking you to actually do bump mapping? If so, have they talked about texture environments (`glTexEnv`) and how those work?

Comment: It's listed as "optional further features to implement" It's not worth too many marks so I can just skip it if other types of textures would be easier to implement and they showed what environment textures are but no implementation examples.

Comment: How are you setting up your [DOT3 parameters](http://nehe.gamedev.net/article/bump_mapping/25006/)?   Edit in a [mcve].

Comment: There is no normal mapping in the old OpenGL. But there is bump mapping, here's a tutorial: http://www.paulsprojects.net/tutorials/simplebump/simplebump.html